Evaluate triangle sides

In the figure, $AC=AD=15,CD=18,DE=10$ and $\angle ADE=90^\circ$. Find $BD$.

By the Pythagorean theorem, clear that $AE=\sqrt{325}$, from here I used cosine Low to find $BD$ but I could not find it
Does anybody have any ideas on how to proceed?



Draw $AF$ perpendicular to $BC$ which intersects $BC$ at $F$. Then $DF=CF=9$ and $AF=12$.

Draw $EG$ perpendicular to $BC$ which intersects $BC$ at $G$. Then $\Delta DEG\sim\Delta ADF$, and then $EG=6$ and $DG=8$.

By $\Delta BEG\sim\Delta BAF$ we find $BG=GF=8+9=17$.

$BD=BG+DG=17+8=25$.


